# Exception in converting Json DateTime In Android

Tags: android, json, datetime

I'm getting a json response date time as shown below,

[image]

I tried to convert this to time formate by using below shown code,

```
    String ackwardDate = deliveryDate.get(position);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String ackwardRipOff = ackwardDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",
            "");
    Long timeInMillis = Long.valueOf(ackwardRipOff); //line 90
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime().toGMTString());
```

`ackwardDate` is equal to the value `/Date(1430204400000-0700)/`

When I tried this it gave me a huge exception I have uploaded that,

[image]

Can anyone figure out where I have gone wrong and how can I correct this, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: because `1430204400000-0700` cannot be converted to long.

Comment: @Kunu how can I covert it? Do u mind helping me with that

Comment: Also replace '-' with blank string.

Comment: A Long cant have a `-` sign inbetween.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `1430204400000-0700` is your mili second time then use

`String ackwardRipOff = ackwardDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",
            "").replace("-", "");`

And if `1430204400000` is your time then use

```
String[] ackwardRipOff = ackwardDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "").split("-"); 
Long timeInMillis = Long.valueOf(ackwardRipOff[0]);
```

---

Comment: that worked but I got the output as 25 Feb 454636 16:00:00 GMT, What is the issue with year? can u figure that out

Comment: I guess only `1430204400000` is your time.

Comment: do u know a better way to sort this out?

Comment: If `1430204400000 ` is your time then use 
`String[] ackwardRipOff = ackwardDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",
            "").split("-");
Long timeInMillis = Long.valueOf(ackwardRipOff[0]); `

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to "-" in your json response, ask your api developer what it really mean, Or I think you can remove "-" like below and try again for the desire result.

```
String ackwardRipOff = ackwardDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",
            "").replace("-", "");
```